# ScaffoldColumn(false) is not detected when generating MVC 2 View in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

If I understand the [ScaffoldColumn(false)] attribute correctly, I should be able to decorate a variable with this and then, when I create a strongly-typed Edit view, that field will show up as hidden text and NOT a Label/Textbox pair.

I am using entity framework and then adding a partial class with an inner metadata class like so:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AlumniInterest_Metadata))]
public partial class AlumniInterest
{
    private class AlumniInterest_Metadata
    {

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DisplayName("Person Id")]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public object person_id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Interest")]
        [StringLength(35)]
        public string interest_desc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This partial is in the same namespace as the EF generated class and the DisplayName attribute IS being picked up so I think things are wired correctly.  I tried changing the type from string to object (based on some google search results) but that did nothing.

Anyone else run into this problem?  Have I made a newb error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC tooling does not reason about ScaffoldColumnAttribute. This attribute is only used when you invoke the `Html.DisplayForModel` or `Html.EditorForModel` methods.

If you wanted the Add View dialog to honor ScaffoldColumnAttribute you could edit the T4 template file that's used to generate a View.

Answer (score 2):

The [ScaffoldColumn(false)] does not seem to work as you would expected. You will need to set

```
 Html.HiddenFor(model => model.person_id)
```

in your view manually.